# Making this function non recursive?

Tags: c++

I have a function here that is recursive, but I would instead like to make it non recursive. I'm just not sure how.

```
  void AguiWidgetManager::recursiveRender(const AguiWidget *root)
{
    //recursively calls itself to render widgets from back to front
    AguiWidget* nonConstRoot = (AguiWidget*)root;
    if(!nonConstRoot->isVisable())
    {
        return;
    }

        clip(nonConstRoot);

        nonConstRoot->paint(AguiPaintEventArgs(true,graphicsContext));

        for(std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator it = 
            root->getPrivateChildBeginIterator();
            it != root->getPrivateChildEndIterator(); ++it)
        {
            recursiveRender(*it);
        }
        for(std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator it = 
            root->getChildBeginIterator();
            it != root->getChildEndIterator(); ++it)
        {
            recursiveRender(*it);
        }

}
```

Its okay if the solution wont work with iterators.

Thanks

Comment: You know, if you make that function non-recursive it'll be very poorly named.

Comment: May I ask why? I think recursion is probably the easiest way to do this. An iterative solution will probably use a stack and manually implement the recursion. Also, `std::for_each(root->getChildBeginIterator(), root->getChildEndIterator(), recursiveRender);` looks a bit nicer than what you have.

Comment: @Chris Lutz The `for_each` may look nicer but unless I'm mistaken since the function is a member function you need a `mem_fun_ref` binder or something similar to make it call right.

Comment: @Mark B - No, it appears to be a class function. I see no `self`, `root` is passed as an argument and it's invoked on the iterator as `recursiveRender(*it)`, not `it->recursiveRender();`. If it is a member function, it certainly doesn't look it. (Perhaps it ought to be a member function, but that's a different subject.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy way is just to maintain your own stack. Psuedoish example code:

```
stack s;
while(!s.empty())
{
    root = s.pop();

    //your code here
    //replace each recursive call with s.push(it)
}
```

Also, casting away constness is a bad, bad idea. It shouldn't be a const argument in the first place if you want to modify it.

Comment: Don't forget to push something onto the stack to get the first iteration going!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would need to implement a stack yourself:

```
clear stack
push first item onto stack
while stack is not empty:
    pop top item off stack
    do action for item (clip, paint)
    push children onto stack (if any)
```

Comment: You might want to note that the children would have to be pushed on the stack backwards to maintain the same order.